# Can’t find C:\Users\Charlotte

Tags: windows-8

I recently inherited a laptop from my mother which I think has Windows 8 on it. I was trying to run a program that asked me to go to the C:\Users\Charlotte folder but I can’t find that folder.

Comment: When receiving a previously used computer the best thing to do is to reset it. Windows has handy built-in functions to do this. Here's the official MS document on the process, you should use the Reset options: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17085/windows-8-restore-refresh-reset-pc

Comment: @music2myear Oh I see, thank you, sorry I’m new to Windows. I’m more of a Linux user.

Comment: You could use commands to open the folder: "**cd C:\Users\Charlotte**", then use "**Start .** " to open it. If the folder exists, the explorer window will appear.

Comment: Basically, unless you have a compelling reason to do otherwise, the best thing to do is to set the computer to as close to like new as possible. Doing this will also make it so you are less likely to run into the odd oddities you've experienced here.

Comment: Unless you are logged on as an Administrator, you won't see other user accounts' profile folder (that's what C:\Users\<username> is) because you don't have rights to do so.  Create or log on with an administrator account, then open File Explorer and turn on the Options to see Hidden & System files.  Then browse in FILE Explorer to C:\Users and you should see the Charlotte folder in the right-hand pane.

Comment: @Debra I'm not sure that's the case. The user folder is not hidden from other users. Permissions just prevent another non-admin user from opening it. It is not necessary to show hidden and system files in order to SEE the profile folders for other accounts on the computer.

Comment: @music2myear : You're correct, of course;  the top level of the folder is visible, but not the contents (for a regular User).  I think my wording in the comment skipped over the detail of "trying to run a program", and yiliazhao provided a useful response for "how to get there".  Your initial advice is probably the best approach anyway, unless there is some specific data that is being retrieved using the program in question.  If they have admin rights to start with, they could just change the password for the Charlotte account & then log in under that.

Answer (score 1):

Right now we are hampered from giving you a 100% answer because we do not know the full context of what you're trying to accomplish, however...

As stated in the comments earlier, unless there is a compelling reason to do otherwise, the best thing to do upon receipt of a new-to-you computer from a family member or friend or complete stranger is to fully wipe and reset the computer.

Assuming you can trust the previous owner, you don't HAVE to wipe, and it is much easier these days to do a full reset of Windows without needing recovery disks.

With instructions taken from here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17085/windows-8-restore-refresh-reset-pc this is how you reset your Windows 8 computer:

1. Open **Settings** > **Update and Recovery** > **Recovery**
2. Under **Remove everything and reinstall Windows** tap **Get Started**
3. Follow the on-screen instructions.

Once the process is complete you'll have what is essentially a fresh out of the box computer setup without errant user profiles or odd settings hanging about to cause problems.